# ERROR from PHP HTTP GET

Tags: php, mysql, http-get

I have some php code that processes a get request which is waiting for an application to post some url to it. Here is my url waiting for the post: http://www.myurl.com/msgid=&msg_content=100+08151000091+1111&msg_sender=2347062698846 
here is my php code.

```
 $msgid = (int)htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['msgid']));
    $msg_content = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['msg_content']));
    $msg_sender = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['msg_sender']));

    $con = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'database', 'password');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysqli_select_db($con,msg);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO messages (ID, Content, sender)
    VALUES ('$msgid', '$msg_content','$msg_sender')");

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Here is the problem. When I post from java code to the above url, I receive the
response is:

```
 IOException - Invalid Http response.
```

But it works when i paste the url directly to a browser. Please where am I am getting it wrong?

Comment: I think the URL's just an example, not the real one.

Comment: @AxelAmthor well yeah so we are going to basically have to guess what is going on which was my point ;-) It's like going to the garage to fix your car and only give them some toy car instead of your actual car.

Comment: http://www.xisysgroup.com/?msgid=&msg_content=100+08151000091+1111&msg_sender=2347062698846 that is the url

Comment: I emphasized what's necessary to know in order to help OP

Comment: an sms company is trying to post to that url, but the support team is complaining of  IOException - Invalid Http response, i guess they are sending from a java code, i was told to check my code very well, i tried the link in a browser and the message was saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

The above PHP code does not "return" anything on the output. Thus, your Java snippet is complaining about the empty output to not to be valid HTML with an IO Exception.

Comment: Where does it say anything about _HTML_?

Comment: the php code is not returning anything, it is just to get parameters from a post and save to database, so i dont seems to understand what you mean by your answer.